# Jazz SCM Continuous Integration - build stream vs. workspace?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, jazz

I am in the process of setting up a continuous integration build for a Spring Roo application using the Rational Team Concert (RTC) IDE and Jazz build engine.  When setting up the build definition, the Build Workspace field on the Jazz Source Control tab allows the selection of either a user's repository workspace or a stream.

The [RTC Continuous Integration Best Practices](http://jazz.net/library/article/474) and other Jazz build resources consistently refer to using a dedicated repository workspace associated with a build user, leading me to believe that this is the preferred approach.  I have not been able to find any information on building from the stream directly.  Our project's stream contains all of the artifacts required to build, and I have tested and confirmed that the continuous integration build works from the stream.  I am unable to think of any reason why I would need to create and manage a specific workspace for this purpose.

My question is, am I playing with fire by building directly off of the stream?  Are there potential downstream complications with this approach that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question in case another SO user has the same question in the future.

After some experimentation, I discovered that a drawback to building directly from the stream was that it ignores the "Build only if there are changes accepted" property on the Jazz Source Control tab.  As a result, builds from a stream may only be done at predefined intervals - it is not possible to configure the build to only happen when new changes have been committed to the stream.

A dedicated workspace is required for the build to accept new changes from the stream and use them to trigger a build request.

Answer (score 1):

There is another BIG difference here.  It has to do with HOW the build gets done.  Let me highlight the difference here.

If you build from a dedicated build repository workspace, then your build workspace already has a copy of all of the code.  When your changes are delivered, and the build is kicked off, then only the changed files (your change set) need to be updated and physically copied from the repository to the build repository workspace.  Since most changes are small, this involves the copying of anywhere from 0.1% to 2% of your codebase from the repository.

If you build from "the stream", then your build workspace needs to be created (you have to compile somewhere!).  So when this is created, your ENTIRE codebase needs to be updated and physically copied from the repository to the build repository workspace.  This means retrieving 100% of your codebase from the repository.

Each file operation involves a call to discover the needed resource, fetching this resource from the database hosting the repository, and then having the Jazz application provide this source file over the network.  It results in a load on the database server, the web server, and the application server.  The more you download like this, the more of a load that you put on these components.

There are some things you can use to minimize this load on the Jazz infrastructure.  Using content caching proxies (using a simple Squid proxy server) can help.

For more detail on your options here, and the relative merits of those options, go and read my blog post and whitepaper on Jazz Performance concerns (http://dtoczala.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/jazz-performance-a-guide-to-better-performance/).  That article is almost a year old now, but still remains valid.  You can also look at the Jazz Deployment Wiki (https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/WebHome), and check out the sections on performance troubleshooting and performance concerns.